# Calculating Air Density and Effect of Air Composition

Tags: physical-chemistry, density

I have to calculate density of atmosphere, assuming that it is:
79% : N2
21% : O2

Does the percentage of gases affect the answer, and how can we find the density with such little information?

Comment: The tricky part for newbies is, that the StackExchange site network expects questions to be more than just questions. There is expected explicitly provided elaboration effort of analysis and thoughts, explanation attempts and basic resource research.

Comment: The density of air depends on which components you consider. Water vapor has some significant effects; components with similar (and low) densities often don't. Also, the density of air cannot be calculated using ONLY the percentages of various gases (assuming you're going without the ideal gas equation, volumes of gases, and other data).

Comment: He can imply conditions according the standard atmosphere. 101325 Pa, 15 Deg C, -0.65 Deg C / 100m till the tropopause.

Comment: @farhhhhhhhhmod If you're still confused, see if these help: https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/air-density#how-to-calculate-the-air-density; https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_air#Composition.